# Promise pending to disable buttons in Ember.js 2

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, ember-data, relationship

I have a `Categories` route with a categories list of course.

When I click on one of them the category route is entered and then the `model()` of this route which loads items and tasks and other things...

[View the demo on Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4f7846f4c96a77c669f94c2ff703631b?openFiles=templates.category.hbs%2C&route=%2Fcategory%2F1)

Everything is good, but:

I have many buttons which I need to disable if `isUrgent` of the `category` model is `true`.

**category.hbs template**

```
<button {{action 'something'}} disabled={{if model.isUrgent true false}}>
```

**models/category.js**

```
isUrgent: Ember.computed('posts.[]', function () {
    let promise = this.get('posts').then(posts => Ember.RSVP.all(posts.map(post => post.get('isUrgent'))).then((values) => values.some((prop) => prop === true)));
    return PromiseObject.create({
        promise
    });
})
```

The `user-task` model has this:

**models/user-task.js**

```
isUrgent: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'urgent')
```

### The problem

What happens is that the buttons are enabled when I open the category page (so `disabled` is `false`) and after the download of the `user-tasks` models (related to that category, because the template is using something like `{{#each posts ...}}`) the buttons are correctly disabled (so `disabled` is `true` now).

### Question

I'm using correctly the PromiseObject? I need to use something else? I need something in the template like `isPending`?

I need to use in template `{{model.isUrgent.isPending}}`? And how? Why is it so verbose in templates?

Why all this? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Use `DS.PromiseArray` instead of `PromiseObject`

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: And after all I'm returning a true / false value, not an array. So I think is not correct.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. try `model.isUrgent.isPending` in categories.hbs

Comment: Can you try it yourself on ember-twiddle? https://ember-twiddle.com/4f7846f4c96a77c669f94c2ff703631b?openFiles=templates.category.hbs%2C&route=%2Fcategory%2F1 I had no luck with isPending!

Comment: The question is precisely about this. How to use isPending in template for disable buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `model.isLoading` check to your attribute binding:

```
<button disabled={{if model.isLoading true model.isUrgent}}>
```

### UPDATE

New demo: [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f7756fe0198f7275ac41a6a786947aaa?openFiles=templates.category.hbs%2C&route=%2Fcategory%2F1).

Basically, you can add few computed properties to your category model:

```
urgentPosts: Ember.computed.filterBy('posts', 'isUrgent'),

postsLoading: Ember.computed.filterBy('posts', 'isLoading'),

isUrgent: Ember.computed.gt('urgentPosts.length', 0)
```

And then ultimately take advantage of it:

```
<button disabled={{if model.postsLoading true model.isUrgent}}>Is Not Urgent (Disabled from beginning and during loading is correct)</button><br><br>
```

While using: `model.posts.isPending` instead of `postsLoading` would also work fine.

How to check if this works:

Go to post model and switch between `status: 'urgent'` and `status: 'notUrgent'`.

Comment: Is not working. You can try changing in `models/post.js` `status` to `'somethingElseThanUrgent'` and try. It's always disabled. I'm updating the demo...

Comment: It is working. Go ahead. Check it. Change isUrgent to false in model and see if my demo is working. If something is failing - then it is your logic to compute isUrgent based on status.

Comment: Yes, I understand it now too. How can I change that Computed.equal? I need true / false based on status, how can I do?

Comment: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/namespaces/Ember.computed/methods/equal?anchor=equal It returns true or false. Why it's not working?

Comment: It's not trivial as you check it for all child entities, I guess.

Comment: I have fixed this.

Comment: Thanks a lot but really two CP (isUrgent and urgentPosts) for this? Really?

Comment: You could also rely on urgentPosts.length or urgentPosts itself as empty array is falsy in JavaScript. By the way what you did here is asynchronous computed property. What you do is asking yourself for trouble. :)

Comment: Do you mean troubles in my application logic?

Comment: See my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45174606/2166409. After working with lots of Ember.js code asynchronous Computed Properties to me are just dangerous.